# Spring MVC can't find jspx-files in WEB-INF folder after jetty upgrade

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm using Jetty for development testing of my applications, through an embedded jetty-starter which is run in IntelliJ IDEA. I would like to upgrade from `8.0.4.v20111024` to `9.4.0.v20161208`, but I'm having some trouble with my jspx files. I also updated `jsp` and `jstl` dependencies.

As per the standard `Spring MVC` way of doing things, my jspx files are kept in the `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` folder.

After the upgrade, the files from this folder can't be found, trying to access them leads to a 404.

I have an index.jspx in my `src\main\webapp` folder, and this is accessed just fine. When trying to access a jspx within the WEB-INF folder, it gives a 404, and then fails to find my `404.jspx`, also located in the WEB-INF-folder, and defined as an `error-page` in `web.xml`. When I move `404.jspx` to the webapp-folder, and change `error-page` mapping to

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/jspx/404.jspx</location>
</error-page>
```

it works. Similarly, if my `controller` is set up to return a jspx in the `WEB-INF`-folder, it fails, but if I change my setup to

```
  <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/jspx/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
  </bean>
```

by removing `WEB-INF/`from the `prefix` and move my jspx, it works.

I'm not really sure where to start looking, whether the problem is `Jetty`, `Spring MVC` or `jsp`/`jstl`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to only occur with symlinked files.

The way of allowing symbolic links/aliases was changed, from

```
context.getInitParams().put("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.aliases", "true");
```

to

```
context.addAliasCheck(new AllowSymLinkAliasChecker());
```

Where `context` is a `WebAppContext`.